# Name of sci-fi story about a favors-based, cashless society?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for the name and author of a short sci-fi history.
I read the story years ago and I can’t remember the title of it.

This is a society with no concept of cash.
Things are acquired when the “seller” owes a favor to the “buyer.”
An individual accumulates favors when she performs a useful task for somebody else.

And thus one of the “wealthiest” people is a guy who repairs bicycles, as everybody uses them for transportation.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. When exactly did you read this?

Comment: Hi.I read the story over 15 years ago. Thanks.

Comment: It's a long shot, but [Neverwhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neverwhere_(novel)) put much value in favors. I don't remember anything about repairing bicycles and it wasn't central part of the story though

Comment: Thank you, @MateuszL but that's not the story I'm looking for.

Comment: probably "And then there were none" by Frank Russel. Does the expression "Plant an ob" ring a bell?

Comment: Sorry, not that one. Thank you for trying.

Comment: @user108131 You are actually correct. That's what I was looking for, "obs". Thank you.

Comment: Similar would be [_Voyage from Yesteryear_ by James P. Hogan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyage_from_Yesteryear); rather than specific obs; wealth in the society was essentially a measure of respect.

Comment: I remember a rediscovered planet, and the natives kept taking things and saying "myob" when they did it, and the modern spaceship people didn't understand it meant "my obligation" and was their currency.  It was a short story from the 70s? Maybe in a Best Shorts or some award winners collection.

Comment: @Engineer: In the interest of avoiding spoilers I won't state what it was short for, but "MYOB" was NOT short for "my obligation".

Comment: Oh right, the landing party thought it meant that... I don't remember the actual plot. So what was the author / story name? I think it's in one of my World's Greatest type collections, and now I have to find out.

Comment: The Science Fiction Hall of Fame Volumne IIA published 1974 sits in my hands; and we begin.   "The battleship was eight hundred feet in diameter and slightly more than one mile long."

Comment: No spoiler, but this sentence will confuse most people today - context: a man talking to his subordinate who is nervous: "You don't look so balanced yourself, chasing that eye around your pan," reproved the ambassador.  LMAO, anyone understand this today? Hint: where does "deadpan" come from? A pan is your face! - technically your brain pan or skull.

Comment: Pancake makeup makes much more sense now, doesn't it? You thought they were using pancake mix, didn't you?!

Comment: It is the third scene on the book "The Great Explosion".  You can loan it at the Internet Library in 1 hour instalments (after free registration) when I am done with it. :-) https://archive.org/details/greatexplosion0000russ

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is "and then there were none" by Frank Russell. You can read it online
[here](https://www.abelard.org/e-f-russell.php). The favors are called "obs" (as in obligations) and are used as an anarchy type economy. Skimming over the story, someone is offered a lucrative (in terms of obs) motor-bike sales job, based on his existing bicycle.

Answer (score 6):

While probably not the answer, as it is likely too recent (only 10 years for the first book), and the favor system is only a side-story, you'd likely remember a lot of other things before that one.

In "[long earth](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheLongEarth)" serie of books, at some point, a parallel society starts to depend on favors (the term is used explicitly) as a currency, due to the lack of central banking system to back up fiduciary money.

Answer (score 6):

Could this be *[Down and Out in the Magic Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_and_Out_in_the_Magic_Kingdom)* by [Cory Doctorow](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?489). This was published in 2003, so 20 years ago. It is 208 pages long, so a short novel.

The story is set in the Magic Kingdom, AKA Walt Disney World. No money exists in the story, all is paid for by "Whuffie", which is basically good-will or happiness that people give to others in return for their service/work/entertainment/goods.

The story is told by Julius, who works at his childhood-dream job of Disney world which is run by teams of people competing to provide the best experience for the visitors. Julius wishes to die, but has low Whuffie and doesn't want to die in that state. People are able to regenerate/revive after they die and there is a complicated plot involving murder that allows a rival team to take over one of the Disney exhibits so that they can revamp it (and thereby generate lots of whuffie for themselves), which Julius exposes and somehow results in him going a bit "off the deep end".

It's been many years since I read it, so my summary may be a little mixed, but it was a decent story.

Comment: I would argue it doesn't match, because "whuffie" is more reputation coin than favour trading - you can't _bank_ whuffie, as the protagonist finds out to his chagrin. Plus you can't just do a favour for someone to get a favour back; if they simply decide they don't like/respect you, you wasted your time.  (One of the reasons I don't like the book is that I can't quite convince myself that Doctorow _intends_ it to be read as dystopian.)

Comment: @DavidW Yeah, I agree no "You scratch my back..." and no banking of whuffie. Also agree on your assessment of Doctorow, which I have found holds true in the few works that I have read. Merely OK stories, some interesting concepts, but can't guess Doctorow's position on them from the story.

Comment: Ha, this came to mind for me too. It was certainly an innovative story!